# react component is not getting called at all from render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a website with react, but some component doesn't show up. Im logging once in the render function and once in the component before the return. The log in the render function shows up but the one in the component doesn't. And there is no error in the console.

the component:

```
import React from "react";
import TaskColumnRowCon from "./taskColumnRowCon";

export default function TaskClumnDays({ title, object }) {
  console.log("showing component");
  return (
    <div className="Task-Column" style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          marginBottom: "10px",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>DAY </div>
        <div style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>date</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <TaskColumnRowCon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the render function:

```
render() {
    console.log("redering component");
    return this.state.dates.map((date) => {
      <TaskClumnDays key={date} title={date} object={this.state.tasks[date]} />;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Try adding a return statement in that anonymous map function. Or you can make it a one liner and remove the braces: ```return this.state.dates.map((date) => <TaskClumnDays key={date} title={date} object={this.state.tasks[date]} />);```

Comment: OMG im stupid. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hahah I do that all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the map function

Try:

```js
render() {
    console.log("redering component");
    return this.state.dates.map((date) => 
      <TaskClumnDays key={date} title={date} object={this.state.tasks[date]} />
    );
  }
```

(I removed the brackets)